# Comparing one arraylist to another and deleting extra items java

Tags: java, arraylist

In this method I am trying to compare all the elements in one arraylist to all the elements in another.  Then, if an element in the first arraylist  does not equal any element in the second arraylist, delete that element.  Something is wrong in either the comparison step or the deletion step, but I am not sure which.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you want clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> compareArrayandList(ArrayList<Integer>compare, ArrayList<Integer>array2) {
    int[] counter = new int[compare.size()];

    for (int x: counter) {
        x = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < compare.size(); i++) {
        counter[i] = 0;
        for (int number: array2) {
            if (compare.get(i) ==number) {
                counter[i]++;
            }

        }

    }
    for (int i=0; i<counter.length;i++) {
        if (counter[i]==0) {
            compare.remove(new Integer(i));
        }
    }

    return compare;
}
```

EDIT: (courtesy of Memento Mori)
The reason your code is not working is that the positions in your ArrayList are changing when you remove an element. Lets say you removed element 3. Now element 3 is different than it was before.

Comment: I assume that this is some kind of homework. Otherwise, I would suggest using list1.retainAll(list2) - it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> compareArrayandList(ArrayList<Integer>compare, ArrayList<Integer>array2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();               
        for (Integer a : compare)
        {
            if(array2.contains(a))
                a3.add(a);
        }
            System.out.println(a3);
        return a3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> a2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a1.add(1);
        a1.add(5);
        a1.add(3);
        a2.add(3);
        a2.add(4);
        a2.add(5);
        a2.add(6);
        Test test=new Test();
        test.compareArrayandList(a1,a2);

    }

}
```

Comment: This solution works.  Just want to point out that it should be return(a3); as the last line, since that was the modified list.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
ListUtils.sum(Arrays.asList(firstarray),Arrays.asList(secondarray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing what you really want to do here. You remove the element(s) which its value is i from the compare array instead of the element at position i which is not find in the second for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<counter.length;i++) {
    if (counter[i]==0) {
        //compare.remove(new Integer(i));  // problem is here!
        // remove element at index i not element equals to i
        compare.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is intentional.  I used that workaround with the counter to try and fix the problem with modifying the list while the for loop was still running.  But it doesn't work right for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your counter array. You can do the comparison in one step if you use an iterator. I believe this should work:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> compareArrayandList(ArrayList<Integer>compare,   ArrayList<Integer>array2) {
    ListIterator<Integer> iter = compare.listIterator(compare.size());
    while (iter.hasPrevious()){
        Integer a = new Integer(iter.previous());
        for (int number: array2) {
            if (a==number) iter.remove();
        }        
     }
return compare;
}
```

EDIT: The reason your code is not working is that the positions in your ArrayList are changing when you remove an element. Lets say you removed element 3. Now element 3 is different than it was before.

Comment: This is indeed the better way, but then he never knows what's wrong in his code!

Comment: So I get a syntax error with compare.hasPrevious() and since I don't know what an iterator is, much less how to use one, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @user2172926 Let me try running it.. I just made that code up. I probably messed something up.

Comment: @user2172926 I edited the code. There was a silly mistake. Should be working now. The idea of an iterator is that it's a way to 'iterate' through a structure. So in this case iter.previous() is giving you the previous value from your ArrayList. In that way, it works it's way through the entire ArrayList. The while loop is checking that there is another value to retrieve, so it stops when it reaches the start of the list. You could actually do this same thing without an iterator by using a for loop and going through your ArrayList backwards.

Comment: @user2172926 the reason you go through it backward is because when you remove an element, previous values in the list don't change. That's not the case when going forwards, because elements get shifted down when one is removed.